# Qt: Post data to server

Tags: c++, qt, http, cas, signals-slots

I try to implement a REST client in order to get a Service Ticket from my server. For those of you who don't know CAS: A Service Ticket can be requested by showing a TGT. The TGT can be requested by a successful login basically. Maybe that is not even relevant.

I quess I have a error in my connect. My server is not even reacting to that connection and the reply is emptry. However for some reason `reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError`is true.

What am I doing wrong?

```
bool Client::validateTGT(QString const & tgt) const
{
    bool isValid = false;
    QUrl url = QUrl("https://localhost:8943/cas/v1/tickets/" + tgt);

    QUrl postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("service", "https://test.de");

    QNetworkRequest request(url);    
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    //QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)), Qt::AutoConnection);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, postData.encodedQuery());
    QByteArray replyData = reply->readAll();
    QString s_data = QString::fromAscii(replyData.data());
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

**EDIT:** `replyFinished` as requested

.h:

```
public slots:
     void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *);
```

.cpp:

```
void CCASRESTClient::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray replyData = reply->readAll();
    serviceTicket = QString::fromAscii(replyData.data());
}
```

Comment: You should call `reply->readAll()` in `replyFinished` slot, not directly after request. Network requests in Qt are async. Try to read Qt documentation and samples. There are everything clear.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but `replyFinished` is not even called.

Comment: @DennisvonEich , I think that you should post the code where you have the `readAll()` in the `replyFinished` slot since this code is obviously wrong. Maybe you have done some mistake there.

Comment: OK, I will add it

Comment: Just added it !

Comment: @DennisvonEich , So, How are you sure the slot is not called?

Comment: Is it maybe because in the Header I don't have a `signal` function?

Comment: Any error signal/slots? Why you don't handle errors? Please, remove your old code and provide complete SSCCE, and explain, why do you return something from your slot.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I should do it, you are right. It is just that I am very new to C++ and I have a limited time right now.

Comment: Your limited time is not a problem of SO community. Be polite, people are spending their time to help you. So you should do a maximum to do your question full and understandable.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov you are right. sorry

Comment: Returning something from the slot was just a mistake. Not on purpose

Comment: Since I want to download from an HTTPS source, I use SSL. I get an SSL handshake error

Answer (score 3):

The slot `replyFinished` is called by the event loop when the reply has arrived from the server, this happens far after your function `validateTGT` has returned.

The `manager` object receives the reply and then emits the `finished` signal, this is when the slot `replyFinished` is called. It doesn't make sense to return a value from there. Just ask yourself, *who is the caller function that will get this return value?* `validateTGT` has already returned, thus it is not getting anything.

Your slot needs to be declared to return `void`, and you should do whatever you want to do with the reply in your `replyFinished` slot.

**In general**, if you have any slot that returns a value, the return value cannot be retrieved unless this slot was called as a normal function (Obviously this is not the case here).

Comment: I edited my code now a bit. This is compilable. I changed the return to `void`. And now I set the data to a `QString`. However, `serviceTicket` is empty.

Comment: @DennisvonEich , are you sure the reply is not really empty? what does `qDebug() << replyData` give you?

Comment: The system I work on shut down until tomorrow. i can work at it tomorrow again. thank you again for your help. I will reply tomorrow

Comment: You can also use the signal `connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));` and if you use SSL `connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));`
`connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));` with the QNetworkReply object, and don't forget to delete the reply object with `deleteLater()` as the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) says

Comment: OK, now I get the error. i have a SSL handshake error :(